# How to use both ssh and sshfs through VPN with single connection?

Tags: ssh, terminal, vpn, remote, sshfs

I am used to mount remote filesystem by `sshfs` to edit code and view files and also login via `ssh` to run the code and any commands.

Now I have to connect to the network via VPN before I can ssh/fs into remote.

Unfortunately, the VPN seems to allow only one connection at a time.

Is there a way to circumvent this problem?

**Related question (less important):** I am also used to run multiple ssh connections in parallel (i.e one additional for `htop`, etc.). Is it possible to open a new session in another tab through the same ssh connection?

Answer (score 1):

See `ControlMaster` in ssh_config: https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config

It allows you to use one SSH connection and multiplex all SSH traffic through that host. Including sshfs. And if you open another terminal window, do "ssh myserver", and then run htop, it will happen on the existing connection too/

Answer (score 0):

Do not run multiple ssh connections. Use tmux, https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki.

"tmux is a terminal multiplexer. It lets you switch easily between several programs in one terminal, detach them (they keep running in the background) and reattach them to a different terminal"

Comment: How does this help with `sshfs`?